# Can't Install babel Plugin `transform-es2015-destructuring`

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to use the Babel plug-in `transform-es2015-destructuring` in my Mocha tests, but I'm having a problem:

```
$ node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test/testMain.js
/home/my/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:313
          throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + (0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + (0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
          ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "transform-es2015-destructuring" relative to directory "/home/my/project"
```

However, when I try to install the plug-in everything works fine:

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring
myproject-reactjs@1.8.1 /home/my/project
└── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.9.0
```

I have the same problem if I use Babel directly:

```
./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js --plugins transform-es2015-destructuring test/testMain.js 
Error: Couldn't find preset "transform-es2015-destructuring" relative to directory "/home/my/project"
```

In other words, NPM is telling me I have the plugin, but Babel is telling me I don't.  I'm tempted to believe NPM is correct, but if it is I can't figure out why Babel can't find the (clearly installed) transform package.

Here's my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

and here's the relevant part of my `dependencies` entry in`package.json`:

```
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.9.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
```

Could anyone suggest how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a `preset` it's a `plugin`, so make sure you are setting it as a *plugin* and not a *preset*.

In your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

In this case you can exclude using `--plugins`

Presets are essentially collections of plugins.

By the way, you can use `node_modules/.bin/babel` to use locally installed executables rather than trying to find them the module itself.

Comment: That explains things perfectly: I completely missed that (incredibly important) distinction.  Thanks!